# How to fire component's actions from template inserted in block-form component Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I wanna fire component's actions from template inserted in block-form component like this:

```
{{#block-component}}
   <p> HTML inserted in block form </p>
   <p> How trigger a action from block-component (not your parent) from this scope? </p>
   <p {{action 'actionFromBlockComponent'}}> Fire component's action!!! </p>
{{/block-component}}
```

The block params enabled in Ember 1.10.0 can help me with this? Or this demand is impossible?

Comment: Do you want to define those actions in the components itself? I am struggling with this too. It is worth noting however that those action do indeed fire but directly to the controller behind the template with the component.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the new block params in 1.10.0 this is possible by doing the following:

```
{{#block-component as |component|}}
    <p> HTML inserted in block form </p>
    <p> How trigger a action from block-component (not your parent) from this scope? </p>
    <p {{action 'actionFromBlockComponent' target=component}}> Fire component's action!!! </p>
{{/block-component}}
```

Note the target of the action set to the block param.

The template of the block-component should contain this:

```
{{ yield this }}
```

It simply passes the component itself to be used as a block param for any template using this component.

Comment: Still valid in ember 2.2

Comment: This is an old question, but as I am using this in ember 2.10, I am wondering if it is possible to send the action back to the parent again?